# Tooltips in plotly generated from ggplot geom_tile

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly, geom-tile

I'm trying to produce an interactive plotly graphic with two vertical axes and on-hover tooltips. The plot should have y1 data as points and y2 data as bars. **Everything works just as needed when I use points for data in both sides, but when I use bars for y2 I cannot get the tooltips to display the correct information.**

With points at both sides tooltips display fine:

[image: points]

With `geom_tile` bars at the right side, every bar's tooltip displays the information of all the bars of the same ID:

[image: bars]

Some complementary information that could be relevant:

- I'm using `geom_tile` to produce the bars because I need to be able to reverse the axes and I was having difficulties doing that with other geoms. I adopted `geom_tile` based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76310566/12372421).
- It is necessary to produce the plotly graphic from a ggplot one, not directly the plotly one. This is part of a large Shiny app that I got to work on, where the ggplot object is stored apart and further manipulated for other purposes.

---

#### MRE

**Note:** I'm not sure if my example is minimal because I don't know well what part of the process is messing up the tooltips. Thus, I prefer to include all elements of my application case here: two vertical axes, reversing and two different geoms including the problematic bars.

** Data

```
# for vertical axis y1 (left)
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"), 
              Date = structure(c(19078, 19085, 19092, 19099, 19078, 19085, 19092, 19099), class = "Date"),
              Val = c(236, 221, 187, 136, 77, 100, 128, 180))

# for vertical axis y2 (right)
df2 <- data.frame(ID = c("J", "J", "J", "J", "K", "K", "K", "K"), 
              Date = structure(c(19078, 19085, 19092, 19099, 19078, 19085, 19092, 19099), class = "Date"),
              Val = c(478, 500, 549, 479, 73, 5, 15, 74))
```

** **Working case** with points at both sides

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

# prepare y2 scaled data
ylim1 <- rev(range(df1$Val))
ylim2 <- range(df2$Val)
scale_y2.1 <- function(y, ylim1, ylim2) {
  ylim1[1] + (ylim1[2] - ylim1[1]) *(y - ylim2[1])/(ylim2[2] - ylim2[1])
}
dfAll <- full_join(df1, df2, by = c("ID", "Date"), suffix = c("1", "2"))
y2.scl <- scale_y2.1(dfAll$Val2, ylim1, ylim2)
dfAll <- dfAll %>% mutate(Val2_scl = y2.scl)

# prepare y2 ticks and scaled breaks
labs2 <- pretty(ylim2)
brks2 <- scale_y2.1(labs2, ylim1, ylim2)

# generate ggplot
ggp1 <- ggplot(dfAll) +
  geom_point(aes(x = Date, y = Val1, color = ID, group = ID), na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_point(aes(x = Date, y = Val2_scl, group = ID, color = ID), na.rm = TRUE, shape = 4, stroke = 0.6) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "reverse",
                     sec.axis = dup_axis(breaks = rev(brks2), labels = rev(labs2), name = "Val2")) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = rev(ylim1))

# generate plotly
yaxis2 <- list(overlaying = "y", range = rev(ylim2), ticks = 'outside', side = "right",
               title = "Val2", zeroline = FALSE, showgrid = FALSE, automargin = TRUE,
               tickfont = list(size = 11.8), titlefont = list(size = 14.6))
ply1 <- ggplotly(ggp1) %>%
  add_lines(x = ~Date, y = ~Val2_scl, yaxis = "y2", data = dfAll, inherit = FALSE) %>%
  style(showlegend = FALSE) %>%
  layout(yaxis2 = yaxis2)

# insert tooltips
tlTips <- paste0("Value: ", c(df1$Val, df2$Val), '\n',
                 "Date: ", dfAll$Date, '\n',
                 "ID: ", dfAll$ID)
for (i in seq_along(ply1$x$data)) {
  aName <- ply1$x$data[[i]]$name
  if (!is.null(aName)) {
    aTags <- grep(aName, tlTips, value = TRUE, fixed = TRUE)
    ply1$x$data[[i]]$text <- aTags
  }
}

# display
ply1
```

** **Broken case** with bars at right side

```
# generate ggplot
ggp2 <- ggplot(dfAll) +
  geom_point(aes(x = Date, y = Val1, color = ID, group = ID), na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_tile(aes(x = Date, y = (ylim1[1] +  Val2_scl)/2, height = ylim1[1] - Val2_scl, fill = ID, group = ID),
            na.rm = TRUE, stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(preserve = "single")) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "reverse",
                     sec.axis = dup_axis(breaks = rev(brks2), labels = rev(labs2), name = "Val2")) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = rev(ylim1))

# generate plotly
ply2 <- ggplotly(ggp2) %>%
  add_lines(x = ~Date, y = ~Val2_scl, yaxis = "y2", data = dfAll, inherit = FALSE) %>%
  style(showlegend = FALSE) %>%
  layout(yaxis2 = yaxis2)

# insert tooltips
for (i in seq_along(ply2$x$data)) {
  aName <- ply2$x$data[[i]]$name
  if (!is.null(aName)) {
    t1 <- grepl("(", aName, fixed = TRUE)
    t2 <- grepl(",", aName, fixed = TRUE)
    t3 <- grepl(")", aName, fixed = TRUE)
    if (all(t1, t2, t3)) {
      aName <- strsplit(sub("(", "", aName, fixed = TRUE), ",", fixed = TRUE)[[1]][1]
    }
    aTags <- grep(aName, tlTips, value = TRUE, fixed = TRUE)
    ply2$x$data[[i]]$text <- aTags
  }
}

# display
ply2
```

Comment: What *do you want" in the *bar* tooltips? Do you want the data for every point that falls on that date? Right now the tips reflect exactly what your code suggests. I think what is throwing you off is that for the markers, there are multiple markers in one trace. `ply2$x$data[[1]]`, for example, has all 4 markers that are associated with 'A'. However, for the bars (or lines), the leftmost green bar is the only thing in`ply2$x$data[[13]]`, so everything in `ply2$x$data[[13]]$text` will show in the same tooltip.

Comment: I want the bar tooltips to look/behave exactly as the points do in the first plot. Thanks for your ideas, I think you're right. At the beginning it was strange to me that the tooltips behaved differently for tiles than for points or lines. Now I think it is just the ggplot/plotly design for that: all points in one trace, all lines in one trace, but one tile per trace. This makes properly setting the tooltips a little tricky in combined plots like mine. I'll do some tests on my own, but if you want to post an answer, given that you seem to have the good direction, I'll be attentive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Option 1:

This modification modifies your `for` statement that you used to modify the tooltips. I used the *plotting* data for the tooltips. I'm not sure if that is the value or ID you wanted for the tiles, but you'll at least see how I changed it.

The `lapply` starts with `if(`...the trace is `markers`. This part of the code is mostly identical to the content in your `for` statement. Note the comment indicating the only thing I changed (`<<` instead of `<`).
The `else(`... is if the trace is *not* markers (lines/tiles).

In the `else`, I extract the text, which looks like this: `"Date: 2022-03-27<br />(ylim1[1] + Val2_scl)/2: 166.8759<br />ylim1[1] - Val2_scl: NA<br />ID: J<br />ID: J"`.

First I split by `<br />` (linebreaks). Then the second break (`"(ylim1[1] + Val2_scl)/2: 166.8759"`) is split by the `:`. Next, I rebuild the tip in the order used in the markers (value, date, then id).

##### The Code

This starts with the object `ggp2` from your question.

```
#----------- this is unchanged from your code ------------
# generate plotly
ply2 <- ggplotly(ggp2) %>%
    add_lines(x = ~Date, y = ~Val2_scl, yaxis = "y2", data = dfAll, inherit = FALSE) %>%
    style(showlegend = FALSE) %>%
    layout(yaxis2 = yaxis2)

#----------- where my mods start -------------
# this is mostly the same content as in you the question's for statement
invisible(lapply(1:length(ply2$x$data), function(i) {
  if(ply2$x$data[[i]]$mode == "markers") {  # all in `if` is from your for() statement
    aName <- ply2$x$data[[i]]$name
    if (!is.null(aName)) {
      t1 <- grepl("(", aName, fixed = TRUE)
      t2 <- grepl(",", aName, fixed = TRUE)
      t3 <- grepl(")", aName, fixed = TRUE)
      
      if (all(t1, t2, t3)) {
        aName <- strsplit(sub("(", "", aName, fixed = TRUE), ",", fixed = TRUE)[[1]][1]
      }
      aTags <- grep(aName, tlTips, value = TRUE, fixed = TRUE)
      ply2$x$data[[i]]$text <<- aTags               # <--------- this is changed!
    } 
  } else {                    # else the mode is NOT markers (tiles/lines)
    if(!is.null(ply2$x$data[[i]]$text)) {           # if text exists
      # split the current multiple stringed tooltip by line break
      aName <- strsplit(ply2$x$data[[i]]$text, "<br />", fixed = T)
      l2 <- strsplit(aName[[1]][2], ":")           # split 'Value' line
      
      # rebuild tooltip for tiles based on the order in markers tips
      #    and plotting data
      aTag <- paste0("Value:", l2[[1]][2], "<br />", aName[[1]][1], 
                     "<br />", aName[[1]][length(aName[[1]])])
      ply2$x$data[[i]]$text <<- aTag               # note the << for envir assign
    }
  }
}))
ply2
```

[image]

---

## Option 2:

*Thanks to Kat's suggestions, I was able to implement an approach which (i) works for combinations of `geom_point()` - `geom_tile()` and `geom_line()` - `geom_tile()`; and (ii) installs the correct Value, Date and ID on each bar. Kat's input was fundamental to have my version developed so I decided it was better to add this code as an addition to this answer rather than posting a new one.*

- I got back to a for loop for simplicity. Anyway it only involves a few iterations.
- This time I used `geom_line()` in combination with `geom_tile()` to illustrate a case where `ply2$x$data[[i]]$mode` doesn't let one differentiate between lines and tiles traces. However, the code is general enough to work also if `geom_point()` is used in combination with `geom_tile()`.
- I prepared two separate tooltip vectors, one for other geoms different to bars and one for bars.

##### The Code

Starting from the `ggplot` object definition.

```
# generate ggplot
ggp2 <- ggplot(dfAll) +
  geom_line(aes(x = Date, y = Val1, color = ID, group = ID), na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_tile(aes(x = Date, y = (ylim1[1] +  Val2_scl)/2, height = ylim1[1] - Val2_scl, fill = ID, group = ID),
            na.rm = TRUE, stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(preserve = "single")) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "reverse",
                     sec.axis = dup_axis(breaks = rev(brks2), labels = rev(labs2), name = "Val2")) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = rev(ylim1))

# generate plotly
ply2 <- ggplotly(ggp2) %>%
  add_lines(x = ~Date, y = ~Val2_scl, yaxis = "y2", data = dfAll, inherit = FALSE) %>%
  style(showlegend = FALSE) %>%
  layout(yaxis2 = yaxis2)

# prepare tooltips
# - for geom_point and geom_line related traces
tlTipsOthers <- paste0("Value: ", df1$Val, '\n',
                       "Date: ", df1$Date, '\n',
                       "ID: ", df1$ID)
# - for geom_tiles related traces
tlTipsTiles <- paste0("Value: ", df2$Val, '\n',
                      "Date: ", df2$Date, '\n',
                      "ID: ", df2$ID)

# insert tooltips
tilePivs <- c()
for (i in seq_along(ply2$x$data)) { # tooltips for traces other than tiles
  # i <- 0
  # i <- i + 1
  aName <- ply2$x$data[[i]]$name
  if (!is.null(aName)) {
    t1 <- grepl("(", aName, fixed = TRUE)
    t2 <- grepl(",", aName, fixed = TRUE)
    t3 <- grepl(")", aName, fixed = TRUE)
    if (all(t1, t2, t3)) {
      aName <- strsplit(sub("(", "", aName, fixed = TRUE), ",", fixed = TRUE)[[1]][1]
    }
    
    # determine if this is a geom_tile() trace, else insert others' tooltips
    if (any(grepl(aName, tlTipsTiles, fixed = TRUE)) && ply2$x$data[[i]]$hoveron == "fills") {
      tilePivs <- c(tilePivs, i)
    } else {
      aTags <- grep(aName, tlTipsOthers, value = TRUE, fixed = TRUE)
      ply2$x$data[[i]]$text <- aTags
    }
  }
}
for (i in seq_along(tilePivs)) { # tooltips for tiles traces
  ply2$x$data[[tilePivs[i]]]$text <- tlTipsTiles[[i]]
}

# display
ply2
```

[image: lines tooltip ok]

[image: tiles tooltip ok]

Comment: Thanks Kat, I was looking for a way to automatically detect the geom_tile related traces and then only treat them differently. In my application I have options for points (geom_point), lines (geom_line) and bars (geom_tile). The last two have `$mode` equal to `"lines"`. Do you have any other idea to automatically identify the bars traces to only edit those?

Comment: Instead of `if... == "markers"`, you can change it to `if.... != "lines"`. By default, lines will be `"markers+lines"` If you're planning on changing the lines to be *only* lines, like the tiles/bars, then you can isolate the tiles/bars with `ply2$x$data[[k]]$fill == "toself"` (or exclude the tiles/bars with `ply2$x$data[[k]]$fill != "toself"`) If this doesn't work, please let me know. We'll get it squared away.

Comment: Thank you Kat, I'll explore the `$fill` option for filtering and come back to you.

Comment: Hey Kat, based on your comments I was able to implement a code that works for `geom_tile()` in combination with `geom_point()` and `geom_line()`, and also gives the correct Vale, Date and ID in the bars. I added it as an alternative option in your answer instead of posting a new one because your code and help gave me the basis to put together my code. I'll wait till the edit is accepted to mark it as accepted. Thanks for your help!