# ggplot legend with geom_tile and geom_line

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom, aesthetics, geom-tile

I'm trying to produce a ggplot chart with two vertical axes where the user can decide which geom to use at each side. The options are lines, points and bars. **I'm having troubles to have the correct shape in the legend when adding bars at the left and lines at the right**.

---

## MRE

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

# prepare raw data
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"), 
                  Date = structure(c(19078, 19085, 19092, 19099, 19078, 19085, 19092, 19099), class = "Date"),
                  Val = c(236, 221, 187, 136, 77, 100, 128, 180))

df2 <- data.frame(ID = c("J", "J", "J", "J", "K", "K", "K", "K"), 
                  Date = structure(c(19078, 19085, 19092, 19099, 19078, 19085, 19092, 19099), class = "Date"),
                  Val = c(478, 500, 549, 479, 73, 5, 15, 74))

# prepare y2 scaled data
ylim1 <- range(df1$Val)
ylim2 <- range(df2$Val)
scale_y2.1 <- function(y, ylim1, ylim2) {
  ylim1[1] + (ylim1[2] - ylim1[1]) *(y - ylim2[1])/(ylim2[2] - ylim2[1])
}
dfAll <- full_join(df1, df2, by = c("ID", "Date"), suffix = c("1", "2"))
y2.scl <- scale_y2.1(dfAll$Val2, ylim1, ylim2)
dfAll <- dfAll %>% mutate(Val2_scl = y2.scl)

# prepare y2 ticks and scaled breaks
labs2 <- pretty(ylim2)
brks2 <- scale_y2.1(labs2, ylim1, ylim2)
```

##### With lines and points it works fine

```
# prepare legend guides
legguides <- guides(color = guide_legend(title.position = "top",
                                         override.aes = list(shape = c(NA, NA, 20, 20),
                                                             linetype = c(1, 1, 0, 0))))

# prepare geoms
gglines <- geom_line(aes(x = Date, y = Val1, color = ID, group = ID), na.rm = TRUE)
ggpoints <- geom_point(aes(x = Date, y = Val2_scl, color = ID, group = ID), na.rm = TRUE)

# generate ggplot
ggplot(dfAll) + gglines + ggpoints +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis(breaks = rev(brks2), labels = rev(labs2), name = "Val2")) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = ylim1) + ylab("Val1") +
  legguides
```

[image: Lines and points]

##### With bars and points it works fine too

```
# prepare legend guides
legguides <- guides(color = guide_legend(title.position = "top",
                                         override.aes = list(shape = c(15, 15, 20, 20),
                                                             linetype = c(0, 0, 0, 0))))

# prepare geoms
ggtiles <- geom_tile(aes(x = Date, y = Val1/2, height = Val1, fill = ID, group = ID),
                     na.rm = TRUE, stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(preserve = "single"),
                     show.legend = FALSE)

# generate ggplot
ggplot(dfAll) + ggtiles + ggpoints +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis(breaks = rev(brks2), labels = rev(labs2), name = "Val2")) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = ylim1) + ylab("Val1") +
  legguides
```

[image: Tiles and points]

##### With bars and lines it fails to show any shape for the bars in the legend

```
# prepare legend guides
legguides <- guides(color = guide_legend(title.position = "top",
                                         override.aes = list(shape = c(15, 15, NA, NA),
                                                             linetype = c(0, 0, 1, 1))))

# prepare geoms
gglines <- geom_line(aes(x = Date, y = Val2_scl, color = ID, group = ID), na.rm = TRUE)

# generate ggplot
ggplot(dfAll) + ggtiles + gglines +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis(breaks = rev(brks2), labels = rev(labs2), name = "Val2")) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = ylim1) + ylab("Val1") +
  legguides
```

[image: Tiles and points]

I've tried with different `shape` values in the `guide_legend()` but the plot just seems to ignore that property. I think it has something to do with the fact that the two first examples use a `geom_point()` call, while the last one doesn't. The `shape` is one of the properties of a `geom_point()` object, but not of a `geom_line()` one.

I know I've read in a SO answer to a question about a legend that someone suggested to use a dummy `geom_something()` call just to have a shape added to the legend. Maybe that could work here using `geom_point()`, but I cannot get to find that thread or documentation on how to add an empty/dummy `geom`.

In case someone thinks of a solution using `geom_bar()` instead of `geom_tile()` note that I'm using the later here based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76310566/12372421) which helped me get the bars to be plotted inverted when one of the axes is reversed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether there is a solution for this problem which does not in fact is a workaround, but we can at least create the legend using a dummy `geom_point()` as already mentioned by you.

Therefore, we can use the definition of `ggpoints` from the above examples and set its transparency to `alpha = 0.0` such that the points are not visible any more. Note that we then additionally have to overwrite `alpha` in `overwrite.aes()` in order to make the bars visible in the legend.

[image]

Edited code parts:

```
# prepare geoms
ggpoints <-
    geom_point(aes(
        x = Date,
        y = Val2_scl,
        color = ID,
        group = ID
    ),
    na.rm = TRUE,
    alpha = 0.0)

# prepare legend guides
legguides <- guides(color = guide_legend(
    title.position = "top",
    override.aes = list(
        shape = c(15, 15, NA, NA),
        linetype = c(0, 0, 1, 1),
        alpha = 1.0
    )
))

# generate ggplot
ggplot(dfAll) + ggtiles + gglines + ggpoints +
    scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis(
        breaks = rev(brks2),
        labels = rev(labs2),
        name = "Val2"
    )) +
    coord_cartesian(ylim = ylim1) + ylab("Val1") +
    legguides
```

Comment: Thank you, seems to work great! Just a question. Would the `alpha` specification in `override.aes` affect the coloring of the data or just the legend? I'm asking because another functionality I need to implement is opacity based on one additional variable. Would I still be able to set custom opacities to the points, bars or lines even if I use `alpha = 1.0` in `override.aes`?

Comment: `override.aes` only changes the legend appearance, the rest of the plot remains unchanged. Hence it should be possible that you set custom opacities to other `geom` objects.